# Issue while using ThreadPoolBulkhead with Timelimiter and Retry

Tags: java, multithreading, executor, resilience4j

Earlier we were using Bulkhead, CircuitBreaker and Retry in our code and everything was working as expected. 
Now we wanted to use TimeLimiter and we modified code to use ThreadPoolBulkhead, TimeLimiter, CircuitBreaker, Retry and Fallback together.
Below is the configuration we have currently :

*Configuration File*:

```
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead:
  configs:
    default:
      maxThreadPoolSize: 50
      coreThreadPoolSize: 10
      queueCapacity: 100
      keepAliveDuration: 5000
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default

resilience4j.timelimiter:
  configs:
    default:
      timeoutDuration: 45000
  instances:
    backendA:
      baseConfig: default
    fallbackA:
      timeoutDuration: 10000

...
Similar configurations for cicuitBreakers and Retry.
```

Below is how we are using it in the code :

```
Decorators
  .ofSupplier(() -> test.hello())
  .withThreadPoolBulkhead(getThreadPoolBulkheadInstanceFromRegistry())
  .withTimeLimiter(getTimeLimiterInstanceFromRegistry(), Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor())
  .withCircuitBreaker(getCircuitBreakerFromRegistry())
  .withRetry(getRetryInstanceFromRegistry(), Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor())
  .withFallback(exception -> handleFallback(exception, transaction))
  .get()
  .toCompletableFuture()
  .get();
```

The Fallback mechanism is same as above the only difference is that it uses the `fallbackA` instance of the timelimiter which is configured to timeout after 10 secs.

While testing the system (20 tps for 5-10 mins) everything works as expected. But when we increase the load duration to 3-4 hours with same 20tps we noticed that for 40-45 mins the system works as expected and transactions are going through; but after that all the transactions start to fail.

The same thing was working without TimeLimter and ThreadPoolBulkhead.

Is there something wrong with the above configurations ? 
Also, when we have thread pool bulkhead, why do we need to provide a separate Scheduled Executor service ? Shouldn't it be taking the threads that are allocated for bulkhead ?

Also, we tried to change the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` to `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10)` at the class level. Then everything works as expected for the positive scenarios but when we put a delay on hello() for 45 seconds and there is a delay on the fallback also (it should timeout from there as well) and load remains same that is 20 tps. 
We notice that initial 2 transactions are successful and rest fails. But we are not sure why those 2 transactions worked (it took them around 1 min 40 secs), they should have failed as well.